# Relationship between database tables

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-key-relationship, relationship

I've got a question relating databases which i can't find the anwser for myself. Currently i got a situation where i have a database with two tables. The two tables are named items and items_sequences. What i want to do is make a relationship between the primary key of the item database and a field in the items_sequences table. Below an illustrated example.

```
| Items |          |  items_sequences |          
|-------|          |------------------|          
|  id   |          | sequence_id      |          
|  foo  |          | counter          |
```

The point is creating the relationship isnt hard. But what i want to do if an Item is made an item sequence should be also made containing a sequence_id with the primary key of the Item itself. And if a Item is deleted the item_sequence should be deleted as well. By the way this should be a 1:1 relationship.

I forgot how this can be done, i would really appreciate if someone would point me to the right direction. Currently i am using a postgresql database if it matters.

Thanks,

Antek

Comment: i don't know but maybe you can use a trigger for that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get this right, you want to look into using [foreign keys](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/tutorial-fk.html) and [triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Answer (score 3):

If it's a 1:1 relationship, could you not just combine the tables?